# call objective-c class method in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

My iOS project contains both objective-c code and swift code.

Say, I have an class named `Task`, it contains a **class method** `do`:

```
@interface Task: NSObject
+ (void) doSomething:(NSString *) value;
@end
```

The above @interface declaration is in **Task.h** file. Other objective-c classes are able to call the method without any problem.

My **swift** code want to call the `doSomething` method,

```
Task.doSomething(“do task now!”)
```

But the above line of code get the following compiler error:

`‘Task.Type’ does not have a member named ‘doSomething’.`

Why? What is the correct way to call objective-c class method in swift code?

(There are no problems with the generated bridging interfaces between objective-c and swift.)

Comment: This may just be a type in the code posted, but the method declaration needs a semicolon in the obj-c interface.

Comment: I just forget to add the semicolon, I have semicolon in my objective-c code.

Comment: Can you clarify which file the @interface declaration you quoted is in? It will need to be in the .h file to be visible. Are other objective-c classes able to call the method?

Comment: I updated my question, the @interface declaration is in Task.h , other objective-c classes are able to call the method without any problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that "do" is a reserved keyword. I tried this and got a slightly different error (about missing a bracket for a while loop), but changing the method to "doSomething" fixed the problem.

I was able to reproduce the error you saw by moving the @interface declaration to Task.m rather than Task.h. Please confirm where you have this code, as it will only be visible to other classes if it is in the .h file.

Comment: If that were the issue, it can be solved by quoting it with backpacks: ```Task.`do`("do task now!")```

Comment: Thanks, but `do` is just my example method in my question, in my real code, the name is definitely not a reserved keyword. I updated my question with `doSomething` to avoid this kind of misleading.  Besides, my interface declaration is in its Task.h .

Comment: Can you add a copy of your bridging header to your question?